# Laravel Spatie media library getFullUrl method not working inside the loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am developing API in laravel. When I try to fetch an uploaded image url inside a loop that gives me this error,

**Spatie\MediaLibrary\Exceptions\UrlCannotBeDetermined: Storage path myAppPath\storage\app is not part of public path myAppPath\public in file myAppPath\vendor\spatie\laravel-medialibrary\src\Exceptions\UrlCannotBeDetermined.php on line 11**

But when I try to get url directly it works.
like this ==>

```
$log = Log::find($id)->getMedia('images');
return $log[0]->getFullUrl();
```

this is my code. below code is not working

```
$logs = Log::where(function ($query) {
$query->where('owner', '=', Auth::user()->id)
->orWhere('owner', '=', Auth::user()->partner->id);
})
->orderBy('date', 'desc')
->get();

    $resArr= array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($logs);$i++){
        $mediaArray = $logs[$i]->getMedia('images');

        $m =array();

        for ($j=0;$j<count($mediaArray);$j++){
            $med = array(
                'id'=>$mediaArray[$j]->id,
                'model_id'=>$mediaArray[$j]->model_id,
                'file_name'=>$mediaArray[$j]->file_name,
                'url'=>$mediaArray[$j]->getFullUrl(), // here not working

            );
            array_push($m,$med);
        }



        $a = array(
            'id'=>$logs[$i]->id,
            'title'=>$logs[$i]->title,
            'owner'=>$logs[$i]->owner,
            'body'=>$logs[$i]->body,
            'date'=>$logs[$i]->date,
            'mood'=>$logs[$i]->mood,
            'created_at'=>$logs[$i]->created_at,
            'partner_log_id'=>$logs[$i]->partner_log_id,
            'media'=>$m,
            'partner_log'=>$logs[$i]->partnerLog,

        );

        array_push($resArr,$a);
    }
    return \response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$resArr]);
```

This is my medialibrary.php file.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
     * The disk on which to store added files and derived images by default. Choose
     * one or more of the disks you've configured in config/filesystems.php.
     */
    'disk_name' => env('MEDIA_DISK', 'public'),

    /*
     * The maximum file size of an item in bytes.
     * Adding a larger file will result in an exception.
     */
    'max_file_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 10,

    /*
     * This queue will be used to generate derived and responsive images.
     * Leave empty to use the default queue.
     */
    'queue_name' => '',

    /*
     * The fully qualified class name of the media model.
     */
    'media_model' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media::class,

    's3' => [
        /*
         * The domain that should be prepended when generating urls.
         */
        'domain' => 'https://'.env('AWS_BUCKET').'.s3.amazonaws.com',
    ],

    'remote' => [
        /*
         * Any extra headers that should be included when uploading media to
         * a remote disk. Even though supported headers may vary between
         * different drivers, a sensible default has been provided.
         *
         * Supported by S3: CacheControl, Expires, StorageClass,
         * ServerSideEncryption, Metadata, ACL, ContentEncoding
         */
        'extra_headers' => [
            'CacheControl' => 'max-age=604800',
        ],
    ],

    'responsive_images' => [

        /*
         * This class is responsible for calculating the target widths of the responsive
         * images. By default we optimize for filesize and create variations that each are 20%
         * smaller than the previous one. More info in the documentation.
         *
         * https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/advanced-usage/generating-responsive-images
         */
        'width_calculator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\WidthCalculator\FileSizeOptimizedWidthCalculator::class,

        /*
         * By default rendering media to a responsive image will add some javascript and a tiny placeholder.
         * This ensures that the browser can already determine the correct layout.
         */
        'use_tiny_placeholders' => true,

        /*
         * This class will generate the tiny placeholder used for progressive image loading. By default
         * the medialibrary will use a tiny blurred jpg image.
         */
        'tiny_placeholder_generator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\TinyPlaceholderGenerator\Blurred::class,
    ],

    /*
     * When urls to files get generated, this class will be called. Leave empty
     * if your files are stored locally above the site root or on s3.
     */
    'url_generator' => null,

    /*
     * Whether to activate versioning when urls to files get generated.
     * When activated, this attaches a ?v=xx query string to the URL.
     */
    'version_urls' => false,

    /*
     * The class that contains the strategy for determining a media file's path.
     */
    'path_generator' => null,

    /*
     * Medialibrary will try to optimize all converted images by removing
     * metadata and applying a little bit of compression. These are
     * the optimizers that will be used by default.
     */
    'image_optimizers' => [
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Jpegoptim::class => [
            '--strip-all', // this strips out all text information such as comments and EXIF data
            '--all-progressive', // this will make sure the resulting image is a progressive one
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Pngquant::class => [
            '--force', // required parameter for this package
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Optipng::class => [
            '-i0', // this will result in a non-interlaced, progressive scanned image
            '-o2', // this set the optimization level to two (multiple IDAT compression trials)
            '-quiet', // required parameter for this package
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Svgo::class => [
            '--disable=cleanupIDs', // disabling because it is known to cause troubles
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Gifsicle::class => [
            '-b', // required parameter for this package
            '-O3', // this produces the slowest but best results
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * These generators will be used to create an image of media files.
     */
    'image_generators' => [
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\ImageGenerators\FileTypes\Image::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\ImageGenerators\FileTypes\Webp::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\ImageGenerators\FileTypes\Pdf::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\ImageGenerators\FileTypes\Svg::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\ImageGenerators\FileTypes\Video::class,
    ],

    /*
     * The engine that should perform the image conversions.
     * Should be either `gd` or `imagick`.
     */
    'image_driver' => env('IMAGE_DRIVER', 'gd'),

    /*
     * FFMPEG & FFProbe binaries paths, only used if you try to generate video
     * thumbnails and have installed the php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg composer
     * dependency.
     */
    'ffmpeg_path' => env('FFMPEG_PATH', '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'),
    'ffprobe_path' => env('FFPROBE_PATH', '/usr/bin/ffprobe'),

    /*
     * The path where to store temporary files while performing image conversions.
     * If set to null, storage_path('medialibrary/temp') will be used.
     */
    'temporary_directory_path' => null,

    /*
     * Here you can override the class names of the jobs used by this package. Make sure
     * your custom jobs extend the ones provided by the package.
     */
    'jobs' => [
        'perform_conversions' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Jobs\PerformConversions::class,
        'generate_responsive_images' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Jobs\GenerateResponsiveImages::class,
    ],
];
```

This is filesystems.php file.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

Hope this helps.

Any suggestion, please????

Comment: What do you have in `config\medialibrary.php` 's key `disk_name`.
Additionally also post the corresponding disk details from `config\filesystems.php`

Comment: @ShreyanshPanchal I updated the question again with these two files, please take a look.thanks

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` successfully?

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` did the fix for me